# Prevent softkeyboard dismiss on the android back button press

Tags: android

I have an activity with an edittext.  when the activity comes, i always focusing that Edittext.
i made the softkeyboard always visible by giving

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

in the manifest. i m doing the functionality on the done button press of the softkeyboard. Actually my need is the softkeyboard should always present when the user is on this activity.
now i disabled the back button press, by overriding and do nothing.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do nothing
}
```

but softkeyboard dismisses on the back press. how to get rid of this. I had tried this [Prevent soft keyboard from being dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366270/prevent-soft-keyboard-from-being-dismissed) but still on the back press keyboard get dismisses. But it comes back by again pressing the back button, My need is backpress should not dismiss the softkeyboard. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @HareshChhelana read the question completely

Comment: my intention is not to close/hide the softkeyboard. Its to prevent the closing of keyboard on the back button press

Comment: This is not a duplicated question. Why you guys don't read the question carefully and simply mark it as duplicated?

Comment: clearly not a duplicated question!

Comment: This duplicate makes no sense.  Preventing dismissal is not at all the same as programmatically showing/hiding.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

create one custom EditText like follow with one interface:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {


    public void setHandleDismissingKeyboard(
        handleDismissingKeyboard handleDismissingKeyboard) {
           this.handleDismissingKeyboard = handleDismissingKeyboard;
    }

    private handleDismissingKeyboard handleDismissingKeyboard;

    public interface handleDismissingKeyboard {
        public void dismissKeyboard();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                             int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            handleDismissingKeyboard.dismissKeyboard();
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

then in your activity create initialize your CustomEditText and use:

```
customEditText.setHandleDismissingKeyboard(this);
```

then implement class and override method and put your code in that

for more info about my answer all thing you need is `onKeyPreIme`, you can override that in your EditText class ( as i post for you ) to handle all key on that, like back Key or any other keyboard key,
I put one inner interface in custom class to get call back from this class to each activity or class that you want, you can do that with static method too, and as you want prevent from dismissing keyboard you can just return `true` in that.

for using `CustomEditText` you can use xml or in java, define that and initialize that like other widget ( Button , TextView , ... ), and only different is you need define this in your xml like :

```
 <yourPackage.CustomEditText ..... />
```

Comment: this answer seems bloated - on `onKeyPreIme()` could be better explained as the main answer, and the extra class be given as an example of how it might be used.

Comment: @ataulm i explain more but i don't think more explain needed, any way thank for notifying me and your suggestion. i hope this be enough as my english is not good i can't explain more than this :)