# How to override the keyboard ondown button?

Tags: android, keyboard, keycode

[image]

I want to invisible my edittext when the user closes the keyboard on down button..

**Try -1**

I have tried KeycodeBack but this is not working

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


        MainActivity.editText2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) ;

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Try -2

I have tried on editorActionListener but that also not helpful

```
editText2.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
               boolean handled = false;

               if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK||event.getAction()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
                       ) {
MainActivity.editText2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

               } 
               return handled ;
           }
       });
```

but `Event` is always `null`.

Comment: try see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721709/prevent-softkeyboard-dismiss-on-the-android-back-button-press/27721774#27721774

Answer (score 1):

In your activity you can catch this event

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And in your Manifest you should add these changes in configchages.

```
    <activity
        android:configChanges = "keyboard|keyboardHidden" // and if you have any other config changes.
```