# Override/disable the soft "hide keyboard" on android's navigation bar

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a Fragment in which the user cannot hide the soft keyboard. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour? I know it is a really bad practice, but I'm just trying to meet the requirements...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to make the keypad always visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509719/android-how-to-make-the-keypad-always-visible)

Comment: If the solution above does not fit your problem please let us know

Comment: No . You can set the behavior of keyboard . But that does not mean it won't close on back button click .  .

Comment: Found the solution here, just had to extend EditText: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366270/prevent-soft-keyboard-from-being-dismissed